# Why isn't astronomy called astrology?

Tags: terminology

Many scientific topics are called ---logy. Like psychology, biology, archeology, meteorology, cosmology, physiology, geology, etc. The adjective "logy" means "knowledge of".

One exception to the rule seems to be astronomy. Why isn't this called astrology? Why not call astrology astronomy? Is it because there is so much namegiving involved in astronomy while knowledge is involved in astrology?

Comment: Historical reasons; see ['Astronomy' or 'astrology': a brief history of an apparent confusion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5209)

Comment: see also this question https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/why-does-aristotle-write-astrology-when-plato-writes-astronomy